# Сложить коллекции laravel с одинаковым id

Tags: php, laravel

Есть 4 коллекции

```
$arr1 = [
    [10 , 0, 1, 2, 3],
    [12 , 0, 1, 2, 3]
]
 $arr2 = [
    [9 , 0, 1, 2, 3],
    [11 , 0, 1, 2, 3]
]
 $arr3 = [
    [9 , 0, 1, 2, 3],
    [11 , 0, 1, 2, 3]
]
 $arr4 = [
    [8 , 0, 1, 2, 3],
    [3 , 0, 1, 2, 3]
]
$result = [
    [3 , 0, 1, 2, 3],
    [8 , 0, 1, 2, 3],
    [9 , 0, 2, 4, 6],
    [11 , 0, 2, 4, 6],
    [12 , 0, 1, 2, 3]
]
```

Первый элемент это id, который определяет надо ли складывать элемент одной коллекции с другим. На выходе должны быть все уникальные id и если id одной коллекции совпадает с id в другой коллекции идет сложение. Как получить $result?

Comment: начните с того, чтобы не думать как это сделать в laravel, а думать, как это сделать на пхп

Comment: Спасибо за совет)

Comment: в чем сложность у вас возникает? заводитет массив под результат. ключи - id. Проходите ваши коллекции и строки в них. отделяете ид от значений. Если нет в результирующем - вставляете. Если есть - складываете. Формируете результат.